# Problem with textcomp package

Tags: fonts

When I put `\usepackage{textcomp}` in the preamble, nothing seems to be added to my MiKTeX package database.

Upon using `\textcopyleft` to insert a glyph from that character set, an ugly bitmap version of the copyleft character appears.

Checking the "Comprehensive Latex Symbol List" reveals that in there is definitely a nice vectorized one, although it claims that the character is obtained from the `textcomp` package.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you try `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`?

Comment: The `textcomp` package is by default in all LaTeX systems; however the outline (Type1) fonts aren't, so you have to install the CM-Super package of MiKTeX.

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` makes it worse ; now the whole document is displayed in a bitmap font.
Adding the CM-Super family of fonts (64.92 MB) to display just one glyph is a bit overkill ;-)
So, I decided to do without the frivolous copyleft symbol.

Comment: Maybe `\usepackage{lmodern}` helps? The Latin Modern fonts might be in the default MiKTeX distro and they're a drop-in replacement for CMR.

Comment: @Petoetje59 Font packages tend to be relatively large compared to other packages. I don't think 65MB are going to be a problem on a decently recent system, that's about the size of a short music album in mp3. Using CM-Super or `lmodern` together with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is the standard way to go. It may also improve your document in terms of being able to search for text, and copying/pasting stuff from it.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps as an alternative, just use

```
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newcommand{\copyleft}{\reflectbox{\copyright}}
```

which mirrors `\copyright`:

[image: \textcopyright]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/textcomp
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newcommand{\copyleft}{\reflectbox{\copyright}}
\begin{document}
\copyright \textcopyright \textcopyleft \copyleft
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is even better !

Answer (score 3):

By chance I found a simple way to add the copyleft symbol using Tikz :

In the preamble :

```
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt](char){#1};}}
```

In the document :

```
\circled{\reflectbox{c}} versus \copyright
```

Comment: I think it is a little too much to load the package `tikz` only to display with `tikz` one symbol ... See the comment of doncherry to the question ...

Comment: TikZ has to be loaded, as the document contains loads of Tikz-generated figures.