# \reflectbox within \caption

Tags: captions

I would like to insert a copyleft sign inside a `\caption`. The following command, given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75673/problem-with-textcomp-package), works outside `\caption`:

```
\reflectbox{\sffamily{\copyright}}
```

and does what I would like.

But this:

```
\caption{A caption \reflectbox{\sffamily{\copyright}}}
```

leads to an error. What surprises me most is that

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\copyleft}{\reflectbox{\sffamily{\copyright}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
   \caption{A simple caption \copyleft}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

yields the error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
\Gscale@box #1[#2]#3->\leavevmode \def \Gscale@x
{#1}\def \Gscale@y {#2}\set...
l.9 \caption{A simple caption \copyleft}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
[...]
```

but this one works !

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\copyleft}{\reflectbox{\sffamily{\copyright}}}


\begin{document}

\copyleft

\begin{figure}
    \caption{A simple caption \copyleft}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas or suggestions? I just want to include a copyleft sign in a caption, using latex.

Comment: Use `\DeclareRobustCommand{\copyleft}{...}` or place `\protect` before `\copyleft` when used in a caption.

Comment: @egreg Surely that's an answer, not just a comment :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\reflectbox` is a “fragile” command (see [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands)), so it needs protection when used (directly or indirectly) in a moving argument.

So you have to do either

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\copyleft}{\reflectbox{\sffamily\copyright}}


\begin{document}

\copyleft

\begin{figure}
    \caption{A simple caption \protect\copyleft}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

that is, using `\protect` in front of `\copyleft` whenever it is in a moving argument (captions and titles, mostly), or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\copyleft}{\reflectbox{\sffamily\copyright}}


\begin{document}

\copyleft

\begin{figure}
    \caption{A simple caption \copyleft}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As an aside, notice that `\sffamily` doesn't take an argument: it is a declaration that remains in force until the group it is in ends; a box command, such as `\reflectbox`, builds its contents in a group. The version with an argument is `\textsf`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this informative answer. I guess `\newcommand{\copyleft}{\protect\reflectbox{\sffamily\copyright}}` would also work, correct?

Comment: @anderstood Your alternative definition would survive only one write operation and usually two of them are involved.